# ContentDocumentLink Limitations when querying using LinkEntityId as filter

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, contentdocumentlink

my apologies if this has been asked somewhere else. I didn't find any answer hence I have to post this question.

**USE CASE:**
I am using database.query(queryString);
In queryString = 'SELECT id,linkEntityId,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE linkEntityID IN :listofRecords';

Here "listOfRecords" is a set of Ids (approx 5000 ids).
The above query returns only 6 contentDocumentLink.
But my org has more than 6 contentDocumentLink for those "listOfRecords".

How do I know if there are more than 6 files?
Because when I run the same query with selected linkEntityIds or hardcoded linkEntityIds (10 "listOfRecords") I get more than 6 records.

**Question**
So anyone has any idea is there any limitation on LinkEntityId when used as a filter in ContentDocumentLink?

Comment: Not sure if you misspelled it only for the question, but the field is [LinkedEntityId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)

Comment: No No, Sorry, I misspelled in the question only.