# ContentDocumentLink SOQL doesn't return all rows

Tags: soql, limits, contentdocumentlink

I have the same question as [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311306/contentdocumentlink-limitations-when-querying-using-linkentityid-as-filter) (but couldn't comment on it)

To reproduce the issue:

```
Map<Id, Contract> limitedContracts = new Map<Id, Contract>([
    SELECT Id 
    FROM Contract
    WHERE RecordTypeId = '0120a0000010S7KAAU'
    ORDER BY ContractNumber DESC
    LIMIT 2000
]);

List<ContentDocumentLink> limitedCDLs = [
    SELECT Id, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.CreatedDate, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId, LinkedEntityId
    FROM ContentDocumentLink
    WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :limitedContracts.keySet()
    ORDER BY LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.CreatedDate DESC
];
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, limitedCDLs.size()); // 2897

Map<Id, Contract> unlimitedContracts = new Map<Id, Contract>([
    SELECT Id
    FROM Contract
    WHERE RecordTypeId = '0120a0000010S7KAAU'
    ORDER BY ContractNumber
]);

List<ContentDocumentLink> unlimitedCDLs = [
    SELECT Id, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.CreatedDate, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId, LinkedEntityId
    FROM ContentDocumentLink
    WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :unlimitedContracts.keySet()
    ORDER BY LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.CreatedDate DESC
];
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, unlimitedCDLs.size()); // 1600 - less than the constrained keyset?!

Integer i = 0;
for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : [
    SELECT Id, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.CreatedDate, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId, LinkedEntityId
    FROM ContentDocumentLink
    WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :unlimitedContracts.keySet()
    ORDER BY LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.CreatedDate DESC
]) {
    i++;
}
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, i); // 1600 - less than the constrained
```

It seems to be [this known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BJoQAM), but it's marked fixed as of Summer 19 and I'm in a Winter 21 org.

Does this mean the known issue still open, or is it something else?

Comment: as an experiment do: `for (ContentDocumentLink unlimitedCDL: [SELECT ... WHERE ... LinkedEntityId IN: unlimitedContracts.keySet() ...]) {..}` and count the records by iterating. This construction uses the queryMore feature of SOQL

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result...

Comment: Ugh. I’d file a support case.  As a workaround, process 1000 ids at a time through chained queueables

Comment: Sounds good - thanks cropredy! I opened a support case and and working around it. I appreciate the second set of eyes!